# Dynamically loading Spring Beans and Components in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reflection

I'm trying to make a Spring Boot app where *plugins* are loaded dynamically from JARs at runtime. I also want the plugins to have access to all the Spring Boot features, most prominently Spring Data JPA. I've already figured out how to load classes from JARs, and now my problem is how to "hook up" the loaded classes (that might be Beans, `JpaRepositories` etc.) to "work with" my main Spring Boot application.

I also might in the future want to have my own annotation system for doing different things with the main app from the plugins, (that I know how to do using reflection) and I would want to still be able to do it after I manage to sort the Spring stuff out.

I imagine I have to tell Spring somehow to additionally look for `@Component`s and other meaningful classes from those JARs, when it's scanning for annotations. I tried with `@ComponentScan`'s `basePackageClasses` attribute but that needs to be constant, and hard-coding this is not an option for what I wanna do.

So is what I want to achieve even possible? And if it is, then can I do it through Java code, or is it maybe achievable by writing some XML configs?

Comment: Adding JPA repository, you would add entities as well right?

Comment: @sonus21 yes, i would. to be more precise, i'm expecting the plugins to be able to use the entirety of hibernate & spring data jpa. possibly even spring web

Answer (score 1):

When you start an spring app, beans are loaded and hooked in its contexts, so if you want to add more to it manually you might need to reload the whole context which may not be a good idea for an spring boot app.

Instead, I would suggest to use spring profiles, so you can define different configurations and based on what you want you can simple enable the one you need.

**Find out more at:**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-profiles

Hope this helps!

Comment: This still doesn't allow me to load different Spring Beans at runtime. I can enable/disable profiles programmatically, but not load definitions of them. This shifts the problem to a higher abstraction, but that abstraction still doesn't allow me to dynamically load Spring Beans from a plug-in JAR. I would have to know at compile time, exactly what every JAR I would load contains.

Comment: Not sure what your plugin jars contains or whether you own their code. If you want to load something from a jar and abstract yourself from what is contains, then there should be a common interface between your app and the jars.
I mean, if you don't want to know what is inside, then at least they (jars) should comply with an interface you can work on.
Otherwise, you will have to know what is inside, declare it in advance and then switch to the right one you want to use. Cheers!

Comment: That is the whole point, I *don't want to know* what will be in those plugins. I want to leave it all up to anyone who decides to create them, and I guess your comment answers my question – it's not possible to tell Spring to use classes loaded through reflection as Beans and Components. Thank you!